# Why Win32 error codes don't match method signatures?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Can someone help me understand why Win32 error codes don't match method signatures and what is the correct way to deal with this issue?

Take for example [SCardReleaseContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as per the MSDN documentation the return type is `LONG`. As per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx#S6), the c# equivalent of `LONG` is `int`. Looking at some p/invoke [example signatures](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.scardreleasecontext) of SCardReleaseContext, the return type is also marked as `int`.

However, the definitions of [WinSCard error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), do not match the `int` type, because the value simply doesn't fit into `int`.

Currently, in my c# program, I have had to define the return value and the error code values as `uint`. This way my code compiles and works. Otherwise, the compiler will complain that the value cannot be converted to int, for instance - `enum ErrorCodes : int { SCARD_E_CANCELLED = 0x80100002 }`.

Can I correctly assume that a c++ compiler will take the value 0x80100001 (which doesn't fit into an int), let it overflow and thus turn the value into some appropriate matching negative value?

Also, am I correct in saying that the c# compiler will not allow such a mistake/bug/flaw to be written and the correct way of handeling this (corner) case is to purposefully "brake" the p/invoke signature and use `uint` instead?

**Edit:**
Fixed the last link, which was sort of incorrect, in it the values were cast to `DWORD`, which happens to be `uint`. Set the link to point to Microsoft's own site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The winapi was designed to be used with a C compiler.  A language which allows assigning an unsigned literal to a signed integer.  Some compilers generate a warning for that but never an error.  Your C# compiler isn't so forgiving.  You'll need to apply two two-by-fours to keep it happy:

```
    enum ErrorCodes : int { 
        SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR = unchecked((int)0x80100001) 
    }
```

The cleaner solution is to have the enum inherit from uint instead.

```
    enum ErrorCodes : uint { 
        SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR = 0x80100001 
    }
```

And change the pinvoke declaration to return an uint instead of an int.  Lying in the pinvoke declaration is a pretty common technique, especially with the ones that take a PVOID or LPARAM.  Of course, you have to know the consequences.  There are none for lying LONG to uint, the types have the same size, only the value interpretation is different.

Answer (score 1):

How comes that they don't fit? Eg. (DWORD) 0x80100006 fits into 32 bits. Of course, it's confusing that you would have negative numbers in .NET, but the value itself fits nicely. Your easiest option would be to change P/Invoke declaration to uint, yes.

Comment: A DWORD is an uint so your value ofcourse fits nicely. I made a mistake in my initial post with the last link, in it the values were cast to DWORD. I now pointed the link to Microsofts own site. My gripe is that Microsoft is declaring a return value of int, but for the error codes is providing a value that does not fit into an int...

Comment: @Marko it depends on the point of view. For me it does fit into int because it has 32 bits.

Comment: you are sort of right about the point of view. But for me Microsoft's view is flawed. Why specify a return value that will overflow your data type? Why not specify a negative value (the result of the overflow) to begin with? Specifing an overflowing value is counter intuitive and not logical...

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that MS simply got it wrong when they implemented `SCardReleaseContext` and that `SCardReleaseContext` should have been declared to return `DWORD`. If I were you I would simply declare your P/invoke to return `uint`.